# React Native - How to store auth token and navigate to other screen after login?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am a newbie in react native, I am creating one react native application with redux. I am only on the login page. Currently, I implemented redux successfully and getting response from API when login credentials are right and getting error if credentials are wrong.

Basically, I have 2 questions in which I am stuck.

1. How to navigate to new screen when login is successfully?
2. Where to store auth token globally so I can identify user is logged in or not on any page?

Below are the response i get when login is successfully

[image]

Below are the code for my files.
screens/Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { LoginComponent } from '../components/LoginComponent';
// import { Button } from 'react-native-material-design';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StatusBar, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connectAlert } from '../components/Alert';
import { login, handleEmailChange, handlePasswordChange } from '../actions/user';


class Login extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    // dispatch: PropTypes.func,
    user: PropTypes.object,
    email: PropTypes.string,
    password: PropTypes.string,
    alertWithType: PropTypes.func,
    loginError: PropTypes.string
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // if (nextProps.loginError && nextProps.loginError !== this.props.loginError) {
    if (nextProps.loginError ) {
        this.props.alertWithType("error", "Error occurred in login", nextProps.loginError)
    }
  }
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.login(this.props.email, this.props.password)
  }

  handleChange = (type, e) => {
    if (type === "email"){
      this.props.dispatch(handleEmailChange(e))
    }
    else{
      this.props.dispatch(handlePasswordChange(e))
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" translucent={false} />
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding'>
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: '800'}}> AfterClix Login </Text>
        <TextInput  
               autoCapitalize="none" 
               onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()} 
               autoCorrect={false} 
               keyboardType='email-address' 
               returnKeyType="next" 
               placeholder='Email' 
              //  onChangeText={event => this.handleChange("email",event)}
              onChangeText={this.props.changeEmailValue}
               placeholderTextColor='rgb(65, 146, 244)'/>
      <TextInput    
              returnKeyType="go" 
              ref={(input)=> this.passwordInput = input} 
              placeholder='Password' 
              placeholderTextColor='rgb(65, 146, 244)' 
              onChangeText={this.props.changePasswordValue}
              // onChangeText={event => this.handleChange("password",event)}
              secureTextEntry/>
        <Button raised title="Login" backgroundColor="rgb(65, 146, 244)" color="#FFFFFF" onPress={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // user: state.authentication.user
    email: state.user.email,
    password: state.user.password,
    loginError: state.user.error
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      changeEmailValue: (text) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_EMAIL_VALUE', text}),
      changePasswordValue: (text) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_PASSWORD_VALUE', text}),
      login: (email,password) => dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', email, password}),
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(connectAlert(Login));
```

actions/user.js

```
export const LOGIN = "LOGIN";
export const AUTHENTICATION_RESULT = "AUTHENTICATION_RESULT";
export const AUTHENTICATION_ERROR = "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR";
export const CHANGE_EMAIL_VALUE = "CHANGE_EMAIL_VALUE";
export const CHANGE_PASSWORD_VALUE = "CHANGE_PASSWORD_VALUE";

export const login = (email, password) => ({
  type: LOGIN,
  email: email,
  password: password
})

export const handleEmailChange = (value) => ({
  type: CHANGE_EMAIL_VALUE,
  email: value
})

export const handlePasswordChange = (value) => ({
  type: CHANGE_PASSWORD_VALUE,
  password: value
})
```

reducers/user.js

```
import {LOGIN, AUTHENTICATION_RESULT, AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, CHANGE_EMAIL_VALUE, CHANGE_PASSWORD_VALUE} from '../actions/user'
const initialState = {
  // user: {
  //   email: '',
  //   password: '',
  //   error: null,
  // }
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error: null,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN: 
      return {
        ...state,
        email: state.email,
        password: state.password
      }
    case CHANGE_EMAIL_VALUE:    
      // return {...state, email: action.email };
      return {...state, email: action.text };
    case CHANGE_PASSWORD_VALUE:
      return {...state, password: action.text };
    case AUTHENTICATION_RESULT:
      console.log("Result", action.result.data)
      return {...state, email: action.result.data.user.email, password: action.result.data.user.password };
        // return {
        //   ...state,
        //   user: {
        //       ...state,
        //       [action.result.base]: {
        //           ...action.result,
        //       }
        //   }
      // }
    case AUTHENTICATION_ERROR:
      return {
          ...state,
          error: action.error,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

config/saga.js

```
import { takeEvery, select, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { LOGIN, AUTHENTICATION_RESULT, AUTHENTICATION_ERROR } from '../actions/user';

const authenticateUser = (email, password) => fetch('apiURL/oauth/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password,
    grant_type: "password"
  }),
});
function* fetchUser(action){
    try{
      console.log("Email", action.email)
      console.log("Password", action.password)
      const response = yield call(authenticateUser, action.email, action.password)
      const result = yield response.json();
      if (result.error) {
          yield put({ type: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error: result.error });
      } else {
          yield put({ type: AUTHENTICATION_RESULT, result });
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      yield put({ type: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error: e.message });
    }
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(LOGIN, fetchUser);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to import a library which provides navigation support.

**Ques 1.** How to navigate to new screen when login is successfull?

**Answer.** Choose and integrate one of the libaries given below:

1. [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)
2. [React Native Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)
3. [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/RNRF/react-native-router-flux)

**Ques 2.** Where to store auth token globally so I can identify user is logged in or not on any page?

**Answer.** You can make use of [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) to store and access the user info when your app restarts and decide whether to navigate to home or login screen. When store is not cleared (app is not closed fully), then use can use store to access the authenticated user

```
yield setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result.user)); // save user in asyncStorage - permanent
yield put({ type: AUTHENTICATION_RESULT, result }); // save user in store - temporary
yield put(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'drawerStack' })); //and then navigate to home

const setItem = async (name, data) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('data stored');
        } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
            console.log('AsyncStorage save error: ' + error.message);
        }
};
```

you can store the result in `store` as well as `AsyncStorage` and access it any where in the app.

Comment: Don't we need to use state for storing token information ?

Comment: Yes, user info need to be stored in two places infact, on the store(global state) and on the asyncStorage/localstorage. If the app is killed then store data is cleared (if not using persistent store), in this case you will use asyncStorage to fetch the user info. otherwise you can use store.

Comment: You should not store the auth token in AsyncStorage as it's unencrypted. Use [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to store secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing logic, you can add a condition on `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Something on the lines of -

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
// if (nextProps.loginError && nextProps.loginError !== this.props.loginError) {
if (nextProps.loginError ) {
    this.props.alertWithType("error", "Error occurred in login", nextProps.loginError)
}
else if(nextProps.email!=='') {
 //this means you have logged in. Your navigation logic will be present here.
}
```

For navigation, you'll need to integerate navigation libraries for `this.props.navigation.navigate(...)` to work

**EDIT**

If you desire to include another variable that defines the user logged in state, then you can use it in your componentwillreceiveprops method like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
// if (nextProps.loginError && nextProps.loginError !== this.props.loginError) {
if (nextProps.loginError ) {
    this.props.alertWithType("error", "Error occurred in login", nextProps.loginError)
}
else if(nextProps.isAuthenticated) {
 //this means you have logged in. Your navigation logic will be present here.
}
```

Note - you'll have to update `isAuthenticated` on login success and login failure redux actions for it to behave correctly.

Comment: I take isAuthenticated prop and set to true when login is successfull. is it correct ?

Comment: yes you'll need to update `isAuthenticated` on login success, fetch it and use it in your componentwillreceiveprops method by applying the apt condition

Comment: Yes thanks for the update, but in this sitution when i click on back button and change the email value, it again redirect me to welcome screen as it goes in to "componentWillReceiveProps" function and isAuthenticated is true already. are you getting my point ?

Comment: it'll be true. that'll be dependent on how you handle those cases. you can call componentwillunmount, change behaviour as you please. or instead of pushing the view on the stack,  you can replace the current view with the new view